# Using rjust() and reducing for loops in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, for-loop

I'm trying to formulate a function that takes a list of lists of strings
and displays it in a well-organized table with each column right-justified.
Assume that all the inner lists will contain the same number of strings.
For example, the value could look like this:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],

['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],

['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

Your function would print the following (right justified):

```
    apples Alice   dogs

   oranges   Bob   cats

  cherries Carol  moose

    banana David  goose
```

Using a given hint, I've arrived at:

```
def printable(tableData):
    newTable = np.zeros((len(tableData[0]),len(tableData)))
    colWidths = [0] * len(tableData)
    for i in range(0,len(tableData)):
        colWidths[i] = max(tableData[i], key=len)
    largest = max(colWidths, key=len)
    for i in range(0,len(tableData)):
        for j in range(0,len(tableData[0])):
            newTable[i][j] = tableData[j][i].rjust(len(largest))
```

I'm appalled at the no. of for loops. As a beginner, I'm still getting out of the 'for-loop' mode. Also, I'm pondering on the best form of attack for this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do this in plain Python. We use `zip` to transpose the table so we can get the maximum width of each column.

```
table_data = [
    ['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
    ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
    ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose'],
]

# Determine the width of each column
widths = [max(map(len, column)) for column in zip(*table_data)]
new_table = [[s.rjust(w) for s, w in zip(row, widths)]
    for row in table_data]

for row in new_table:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana']
[' Alice', '    Bob', '   Carol', ' David']
['  dogs', '   cats', '   moose', ' goose']
```

If you don't really need a new 2D list, and you just want to print the data, you can do something like this:

```
for row in table_data:
    print(*(s.rjust(w) for s, w in zip(row, widths)))
```

**output**

```
apples oranges cherries banana
 Alice     Bob    Carol  David
  dogs    cats    moose  goose
```

---

Here's a new version that transposes the table.

```
widths = [max(map(len, row)) for row in table_data]
new_table = [[s.rjust(w) for s, w in zip(row, widths)] for row in zip(*table_data)]
for row in new_table:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
['  apples', 'Alice', ' dogs']
[' oranges', '  Bob', ' cats']
['cherries', 'Carol', 'moose']
['  banana', 'David', 'goose']
```

Comment: zip is exactly what I was toying with :) Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed the output isn't the same as the desired one? Working on that now.

Comment: @db18 Ok. I see that you want the output transposed. :oops: I'll add a new version.

Comment: I feel the urge to say this whenever I see that last remaining `for` loop for printing: `collections.deque((print(row) for row in new_table), maxlen=0)`. I don't actively recommend it though :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist For my private use, I'd be tempted to do `print(*map(' '.join, new_table), sep='\n')` but I try to keep things simpler on SO. ;)

Answer (score 3):

### with Pandas Combination of `to_string`, `index=False`, `transpose`, and `splitlines`

There is a `header=None` option, but it messes up the alignment for some unknown reason.  So I leave the header and lop it off with `splitlines[1:]`

```
import pandas as pd
print('\n'.join(pd.DataFrame(table_data).T.to_string(index=False).splitlines()[1:]))

  apples  Alice   dogs
 oranges    Bob   cats
cherries  Carol  moose
  banana  David  goose
```

---

### f-strings + `str.format`

Construct a `str.format` function that is based on max string lengths.
Inspired by [PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51937408/2336654)

```
f = '  '.join([f"{{:>{max(map(len, r))}}}" for r in table_data]).format
print('\n'.join([f(*t) for t in zip(*table_data)]))

  apples  Alice   dogs
 oranges    Bob   cats
cherries  Carol  moose
  banana  David  goose
```

#### Details

This:

```
'  '.join([f"{{:>{max(map(len, r))}}}" for r in table_data])
```

Produces a string that looks like:

```
'{:>8}  {:>5}  {:>5}'
```

The `8, 5, 5` are the max string lengths per row.  I convert this to a format function by appending a `.format` at the end.  It is now a function that accepts 3 positional arguments and formats a string with the prescribed spacing.

Answer (score 2):

I thought you *had to* write the algorithm by yourself, but in your attempt you have used `numpy`, so I am assuming you can also use `pandas`.

You can just load your data in a data frame, transpose it and make use of the already-built `__repr__` of pandas `DataFrame` class

In other words,

```
pd.DataFrame(arr).T.__repr__()
```

which yields

```
'          0      1      2\n0    apples  Alice   dogs\n1   oranges    Bob   cats\n2  cherries  Carol  moose\n3    banana  David  goose'
```

Such that, if you `print` it, you get

```
          0      1      2
0    apples  Alice   dogs
1   oranges    Bob   cats
2  cherries  Carol  moose
3    banana  David  goose
```

If you want to not print the column ids, you can play with the `__repr__` output

```
print('\n'.join([x[1:] for x in df.__repr__().split('\n')[1:]]))


    apples  Alice   dogs
   oranges    Bob   cats
  cherries  Carol  moose
    banana  David  goose
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tableData = [
    ['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
    ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
    ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']
]

# Determine maximum column width
colWidth = 0
for x in tableData:
    colWidth = max(colWidth, len(max(x, key=len)))

# Use zip to "flip" your rows and columns
# Note that the * first unpacks your list of lists 

for row in zip(*tableData):
     # Join each row element together into a string, right justifying each element to your column width as you go
    print ''.join([ele.rjust(colWidth) for ele in row])
```